# character doesn t push from wall when wall jumping in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    dirY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical") && IsGrounded())
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, dirY * jumpforce);
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical") && ((rb.velocity.y > 0f) || (rb.velocity.y < 0f)) && doublejump == true && dirY > 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, dirY * jumpforce);
        doublejump = false;
    }
    if ((IsWalledright() || IsWalledleft()) && (rb.velocity.y < 0) && !IsGrounded() && Mathf.Abs(dirX) > 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, -slidingspeed);
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x - 1, dirY * jumpforce);
        }
    }
    if (IsGrounded() == true)
    {
        doublejump = true;
    }
    UpdateAnimationState();

}
```

i want my character to wall jump moving away from the wall but that doesn t seem to happen using this code (specifically line 23)
instead my character kept jumping and still facing the wall

Edit : the problem seems to be that the rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * movespeed, rb.velocity.y); is opposing  rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x - 1, dirY * jumpforce);
can i get a fix on that

Comment: which is line 23? In general I don't see where you ever use he value of `dirX` (except once for checking if it is pressed at all) ... should `rb.velocity.x - 1` maybe rather be `rb.velocity.x * -1`?

Comment: dirX is used to calculate velocity after dirY has a value assigned to it

Comment: I think your issue is that you're adding horizontal velocity to jump away from the wall with `rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x - 1, dirY * jumpforce);` but since you're most likely still holding down your horizontal input button, the next loop in the update function is going to overwrite the velocity you just changed with `rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * movespeed, rb.velocity.y);`

Comment: oh didn't see the very fist velocity change ^^